# Нужен ли нам блок со списком горячих вопросов?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-отклонено, вопросы, актуальные-вопросы-сети

Сначала я думал, что у нас его нет, т.к. сайт не на английском, но на том же [esSO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions) этот блок есть. И даже на [РЯ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) есть.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Спросил на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335325/260198). Как я понял, если захотим, то могут и нам включить этот блок. Нужен ли он нам?

---

**UPD:** включать не будут, т.к:

1. Компания не думает, что нам оно надо.
2. Считают, что у нас мало кто понимает английский.
3. Не авторизованные пользователи не смогут этот блок отключить.

Comment: Помню, что его убрали специально, скорее всего из-за нерусскоязычного контента

Comment: @PashaPash да вот тоже такое припоминаю, но нагуглить тред на нашей Мете не смог.

Comment: Было бы хорошо к этому всему добавить показатели (ответы, рейтинг и тд)

Answer (score 23):

## Да

Я за то, чтобы блок вернуть.

Тем более, оказалось, что в настройках профиля есть ещё один флаг, позволяющий индивидуально отключить блок тем, кому он не нравится.

Answer (score 6):

Учитывая, что (как уже упомянуто в связанном вопросе на MSE) имеется [индивидуальная настройка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current), позволяющая отображать/прятать эти ссылки, то было бы справедливым оставить право решать самому пользователю, а не блокировать глобально для всего сайта.

Как некий компромисный вариант можно было бы опцию, скрывающую hot network questions, активировать по умолчанию для участников, у которых аккаунт был создан через ruSO. Но это явно будет требовать б**о**льших телодвижений от разработчиков, нежели просто вернуть работоспособность как на большинстве сайтов сети.

P.S. тем не менее, у меня, кстати, настройками эти HNQ были отключены.

Comment: Эм.. Так значит настройка для пользователя уже есть...

Comment: @Qwertiy да, можно посмотреть по [ссылке из вопроса на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335325/). Добавил линк на настройку заодно.

Answer (score -5):

Да включить но только на Русском )))

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете?

Answer (score -5):

#### Зачем вообще нужен блок ГВС?

Вопрос, посвященный целям ГВС раскрыт в деталях на MSE («[What is the Goal of “Hot Network Questions”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219922/274323)»). В двух словах, ГВС — это способ направить трафик с популярных сайтов, например, Stack Overflow на английском, на менее популярные, например, [сайт посвященный LEGO](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/).

#### Чего мы хотим добиться добавлением блока к нам на сайт?

Обычно сообщества активно настаивают на *включении их сайта в список отображаемых вопросов в блоке*, так как основная польза от нахождения в списке ГВС — реклама сообщества на больших сайтах сети и, как результат, новые участники для сайта.

У нас же ситуация обратная. Предложение добавить блок к нам, то есть сделать Stack Overflow на русском источником новых участников для других сайтов сети.

#### Почему блок был выключен?

Цель — максимизировать соотношение сигнала к шуму: в вакууме, это была бы страничка только с текстом вопроса и ответами к нему. В реальной жизни нам нужны механизмы модерации (голосования, закрытия, тревоги), системные инструменты (вход, выход и тд) и, иногда, немного рекламы. Правило остается прежним: меньше всего, не относящегося к вопросу или ответам — лучше.

Stack Overflow на русском посещают русскоязычные пользователи, ГВС ведут только на англоязычные ресурсы. Как результат, пользы от блока на нашем сайте видится не много. Представьте, например, блок на немецком или японском. Стали бы вы переходить? По аналогичной причине наш сайт был исключен из ГВС.

Таким образом, на мой взгляд, было бы полезно определить *зачем* нам нужен блок ГВС, что это даст сообществу или платформе?

П.С. Вместо ГВС наше сообщество использует баннеры, которые отображаются на Stack Overflow на английском всем, кто может знать русский язык. Когда я думаю о ГВС на Stack Overflow на русском, в уме маячит предложение создать баннеры ведущие на сайты посвященные русскому языку и разместить их у нас на сайте. Что думаете?

Comment: Пользователь в настройках может отключить HNQ. Пускай каждый сам решает, хочет видеть их или нет.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Stack Overflow оптимизируется под чтение, например, как Википедия. Подавляющая часть тех, кто увидит этот блок не зарегистрирована на сайте. С другой стороны, те кто знают про опцию скрытия, вероятно, знают и про stackexchange.com, где на главной довольно объемный список ГВС.

Comment: По-умолчанию (и для незарегистрированных) можно выключенной оставлять эту галку.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Ага — отключить блок на сайте, что мы и сделали.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что сайт читают порядка миллиона человек в месяц. Добавляя блок мы добавляем немного дискомфорта каждому из них. Вопрос: что мы получаем взамен?

Comment: Так я же говорю, по умолчанию не показывать, а кто хочет может - включит в настройках.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Если я чего–то не упустил, такой возможности нет. Мы можем лишь показывать, а кто не хочет — может скрыть. Технической реализации инверсного варианта нет. Рекомендую задать вопрос–предложение на MSE, возможно ребята что–то подскажут.

Comment: Я вообще с Катей это в декабре обсуждал. Она просила после НГ отписаться. У меня вопрос больше такой: текущий вопрос можно считать как волю сообщества?

Comment: Странно ещё то, что на esSO есть этот блок, а на jaSO и ptSO нету.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "Добавляя блок мы добавляем немного дискомфорта каждому из них". Какого дискомфорта? Возьмите хотя бы самый захудалый сайт на SE: [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/). Даже у них ГВС есть. Да вообще на любом сайте SE есть кроме нашего. Почему мы должны быть другими?

Comment: Николас прав, в том что наличие ГВС не особо оправдано. Дискомфорт от него хоть и невелик, но не нулевой, а вот пользователей - много. Решение Suvitruf было бы хорошим при текущем раскладе. Как расширение идеи - включать ГВС по умолчанию тому кому он вероятно нужен (например у кого есть более 5 связанных учеток или 500 репы на англ.сайтах).

Comment: Блок - это возможность увидеть интересные вопросы и зайти почитать. Естественно, для тех, кто знает английский. Но мы всё-таки на сайте программистов, а у программистов обычно с ним нормально.

Comment: Я не улавливаю логику ответа. Потому что любые приведенные аргументы сразу упираются во встречный вопрос: почему на esSО эти же самые аргументы, очевидно, не работают, потому что там-то блок есть?

Comment: А почему на [РЯ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) такой блок есть?

Comment: @Yaant да даже на [РЯ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) этот блок есть.

Comment: @Suvitruf Хех, Л - логика.